# org-mode: How to perform an agenda keyword search limited to headline text?

Tags: org-mode

The org-mode agenda command 's' will perform a keyword search over both the headline and the body text of org-mode items.  Is there a way to limit the search to just the headline text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enter a regular expression to match only headlines.

For example:

```
{^\*+.*mykeyword}
```

will search for lines starting with one or more `*`, and containing "mykeyword".

Answer (score 0):

Adding a `*` before entering any keyword is a better and shorter way of searching for headlines only.

For details and other tricks, see [Advanced searching](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/advanced-searching.html)

Comment: The answer is correct, I do not understand why one would down vote it. Please read the linked article on "Limiting full text searches" about advanced agenda searching.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Thank you!